# GeoServer installation and Java Windows 10

Tags: geoserver, windows-10

I have installed GeoServer by:

- Downloading https://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.19.1/geoserver-2.19.1-bin.zip/download
- Extracting it to C:\Program Files\GeoServer
- Setting JAVA_HOME environment variable to the folder where java.exe is found

But it won't start:

> The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly. Please
> install Java or, if present but not in the path, set this environment
> variable via the following command:    set JAVA_HOME=[path to Java]

What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set the path one step too deep.

The example path in the error message `set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8` gives a hint and if you open the startup.bat file with a text editor you will see a line

`if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" goto badJava`.

Remove `\bin` from your JAVA_HOME and GeoServer will start.